# Find number of decimal digits of a variable in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Given a variable x = 12.3442

I want to know the number of decimal digits of the variable. In this case the result would be 4. How can I do this without trial and error?

Comment: You can't - real numbers are almost always represented as floating-point numbers for which "number of decimal digits" doesn't make sense.

Comment: @H2CO3 Of course it does make sense. Yes, there is a problem stemming from the approximate nature of the floating point representation. Solving it is part of the question. Convert that binary representation to decimal (it happens every time you print a number on screen...) and figure out how many digits you need to drop from the end before counting the remaining nonzero ones. Every time you do arithmetic operations with floating point numbers you lose some precision, so you could say that it's impossible to do arithmetic operations on a computer--that's not very productive thinking, is it?

Comment: @Szabolcs Nope, I'm not saying that. Probably you don't understand the problem, but floating-point calculations aren't exact and the restults are representation-dependent. It's always the user who has to specify what precision he wants to work with - that's not implicit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the "number of decimal digits" does not make sense in most cases, but I think that this may be what you're looking for:

```
>> num = 1.23400;
>> temp = regexp(num2str(num),'\.','split')

temp = 

    '1'    '234'
>> length(temp{2})

ans =

    3
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for more than 4 decimal digits: Try: `num = 1.23456789;` It gives you `ans = 4`, a maximum of 4 decimal digits.

Comment: Yeah. Something like `temp = regexp(num2str(num,15),'\.','split')` does work, but that won't always either. I'd love to learn something better.

Comment: I didn't know about the second input to num2str. Although not bullet-proof, I believe that would absolutely serve its purpose in this case..

Comment: Nice fast way to count the number of digits of a natural number.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a compact way:

```
y = x.*10.^(1:20)
find(y==round(y),1)
```

Assumes that `x` is your number and 20 is the maximum number of decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

```
%If number is less than zero, we need to work with absolute value
if(value < 0)
   num = abs(value);
else
   num = value;
end
d = 0; % no of places after decimal initialised to 0.
x = floor(num);
diff = num - x;
while(diff > 0)
     d = d + 1;
     num = num * 10;
     x = floor(num);
     diff = num - x;
 end

 %d is the required digits after decimal point
```

Answer (score 0):

For a number `a` and the assumption that it will have less than 28 decimal places here is something compact and reliable:

```
numDP = length(num2str(a, 28)) - strfind(num2str(a, 28),'.');
```

Converting to string makes good use of string comparison functions in Matlab although it is a little clumsy.

Answer (score -1):

Works under all conditions (if it is decimal):

```
temp = strsplit(num2str(num),'.');
result = length(temp{2});
```